# A small bug: period on the next line after MathJaX

Tags: bug, mathjax

André Nicolas wrote  an answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/216264/trigonometry-without-sine-and-cosine), in which he mentions "the line through $A$ and $B$."  It appears in my browser window as:

the line through $A$ and $B$
.

with the period on the next line.  Maybe that changes with the window geometry, or maybe not.  But that shouldn't happen.

(Usually when I see this it's because someone typed some "displayed" TeX in which they put the period OUTSIDE of TeX, and the fix is to move it inside, where it should have been.  But that doesn't apply here.)

**Later note:** In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/217008/inequality-in-integrals) posting, the period sits alone on the next line after *displayed* TeX, simply because the line is so long that it starts wrapping right at the point where the only thing left to display is the period!

A screen shot of a similar problem provided in a duplicate report:

[image: Screen shot illustrating the problem]

Comment: If the period is part of the mathematical statement, then is should be inside the $\LaTeX$. In this case, it is not, so I think it is in the proper place here. IF the period is moved to a line by itself, that is perhaps a problem with the integration of MathJax and the markup language.

Comment: So the bug I'm reporting here is "a problem with the integration of MathJax and the markup language."

Comment: [The line in your later note](http://i.stack.imgur.com/F05LJ.png) looks fine on my computer (Mac OSX 10.5.8, Firefox 15)

Comment: Both look fine to me.

Comment: Adding a screenshot would probably be a reasonable thing to do in a bug report. (Especially since another user said in a comment that both linked questions are displayed correctly for them.) This is what I get in 49.0.2623.87 with choice of HTML-CSS as Math Renderer: http://i.stack.imgur.com/KI87y.png